# Locating duplicated entries in a column of a dataframe?

Tags: r, subset, mean

In rows, 11:13, and in 14:16, it can be observed that there are duplicate entries in column 'C2_xsampa' for 'm:' and 'n:'. Each value in 'C2_xsampa' has two levels, Singleton or Geminate but it is not the case among 'm:' and 'n:'. This yields wrong mean values for numeric columns.

My question is: How do I filter which row is being duplicated? I have manually checked the parent dataset through which means values are obtained. All looks fine there.

Earlier, I was using subset () to rectify the 'real' errors in entry.

Data:

```
C2_xsampa Consonant Speaker C1.dn C2.dn V1.dn V2.dn total.dn
 1 "d_d"     Singleton    8.5  11.9   7.82 13.0   7.65     40.3
 2 "d_d:"    Geminate     9    11.6  11.9  11.4   7.46     42.3
 3 "dZ"      Singleton    8.31  7.79  7.47 14.9   9.81     40.0
 4 "dZ:"     Geminate     8.08  7.72 13.4  12.8   9.61     43.6
 5 "g"       Singleton    9    12.1  11.3  11.9   8.56     43.9
 6 "g:"      Geminate     8.69 11.3  11.1  12.7  10.2      45.3
 7 "k"       Singleton    9.5  12.3  14.4   9.71  6.97     43.4
 8 "k:"      Geminate     9    14.7  16.1  10.1   7.37     48.2
 9 "l"       Singleton    8.69 11.9   6.33 11.5  10.2      40.0
10 "l:"      Geminate     8.81 11.3  10.0  10.0  11.5      42.8
11 "m"       Singleton    8.36 13.6   9.11 11.1   9.20     43.0
12 "m:"      Geminate     8.85 13.7  10.9   9.95  8.42     43.0
13 "m: "     Geminate    14    14.6  12.4   5.66  5.01     37.7
14 "n"       Singleton    8    15.1   4.44 11.6   8.99     40.2
15 "n:"      Geminate     8.21 21.4  10.1  10.2   9.32     51.0
16 "n: "     Geminate    11.3  32.0  10.4   8.09  7.94     58.5
17 "p"       Singleton    8.4  11.2  11.9   7.98  6.53     37.7
18 "p:"      Geminate     8.81 13.2  12.7   8.57 11.3      45.8
19 "t`"      Singleton    9    12.9  10.5   8.69  9.20     41.3
20 "t`:"     Geminate     9    13.1  13.1   8.39 10.6      45.2
```

Thanks.

Comment: While I am able to spot the problem, it is unclear how you want to differ between the "right" or "wrong" duplicate.  Just looking at your example it appears that the values for the 2nd `Geminate` are significantly higher than for the first entry. From the "correct" cases it follows that the values are relatively close. Thus you can calculate the difference - for example - of `total.dn` per `C2_sampa` group. You then delete (`filter`) the rows with the higher differences. !!! Make sure that my understanding is correct !!!.

Comment: You speak also about a source data set and using subset() to fix things. Typically, additional rows are injected with joins when you merge things. Or your code does create rows and you need to catch another exception.

Comment: great we brought this to a successful end. The code from @Zaw looks pretty efficient. Please note that we cannot really tell you why the two entries crop up. This would require to see what you do to construct the dataset. From own experience, I know that I regularly create multiples with a merge/join or when I add a conditional row to a data set. These duplicate are typically because I forget to catch a condition. If you provide an example how the rows 11:13 and 14:16 are produced, we might be able to spot what goes wrong. Anyway, you got what you need(ed). Good luck with the further journey!

Comment: @Ray, the entries had some extra spaces after the values 'm:' and 'n:'. That is why, the output showed two different factors for the same value in column 'C2_xsampa'. 

It was a manual error at the time of making the parent dataset. Glad, I posted here, there were a few other mistypes in the parent dataset that were rectified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there are unnecessary symbols and spaces in some of the values of `C2_xsampa`. Here is a suggestion using `{tidyverse}`. First, it removes the symbols/spaces and then identifies duplicated rows by `C2_xsampa` and `Consonant`. You can filter the duplicated rows using `dup` column.

```
library(tidyverse)
   
dat1 <- dat %>% 
  mutate(C2_xsampa = str_trim(C2_xsampa)) %>% 
  group_by(C2_xsampa, Consonant) %>% 
  mutate(dup = n()) %>%
  ungroup()

dat1

# # A tibble: 20 x 9
#    C2_xsampa Consonant Speaker C1.dn C2.dn V1.dn V2.dn total.dn   dup
#    <chr>     <chr>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <int>
#  1 d_d       Singleton    8.5  11.9   7.82 13     7.65     40.3     1
#  2 d_d:      Geminate     9    11.6  11.9  11.4   7.46     42.3     1
#  3 dZ        Singleton    8.31  7.79  7.47 14.9   9.81     40       1
#  4 dZ:       Geminate     8.08  7.72 13.4  12.8   9.61     43.6     1
#  5 g         Singleton    9    12.1  11.3  11.9   8.56     43.9     1
#  6 g:        Geminate     8.69 11.3  11.1  12.7  10.2      45.3     1
#  7 k         Singleton    9.5  12.3  14.4   9.71  6.97     43.4     1
#  8 k:        Geminate     9    14.7  16.1  10.1   7.37     48.2     1
#  9 l         Singleton    8.69 11.9   6.33 11.5  10.2      40       1
# 10 l:        Geminate     8.81 11.3  10    10    11.5      42.8     1
# 11 m         Singleton    8.36 13.6   9.11 11.1   9.2      43       1
# 12 m:        Geminate     8.85 13.7  10.9   9.95  8.42     43       2
# 13 m:        Geminate    14    14.6  12.4   5.66  5.01     37.7     2
# 14 n         Singleton    8    15.1   4.44 11.6   8.99     40.2     1
# 15 n:        Geminate     8.21 21.4  10.1  10.2   9.32     51       2
# 16 n:        Geminate    11.3  32    10.4   8.09  7.94     58.5     2
# 17 p         Singleton    8.4  11.2  11.9   7.98  6.53     37.7     1
# 18 p:        Geminate     8.81 13.2  12.7   8.57 11.3      45.8     1
# 19 t`        Singleton    9    12.9  10.5   8.69  9.2      41.3     1
# 20 t`:       Geminate     9    13.1  13.1   8.39 10.6      45.2     1
```

Here is the code for the dataset:

```
dat <- read.table(
  text = '
  C2_xsampa Consonant Speaker C1.dn C2.dn V1.dn V2.dn total.dn
 1 "d_d"     Singleton    8.5  11.9   7.82 13.0   7.65     40.3
 2 "d_d:"    Geminate     9    11.6  11.9  11.4   7.46     42.3
 3 "dZ"      Singleton    8.31  7.79  7.47 14.9   9.81     40.0
 4 "dZ:"     Geminate     8.08  7.72 13.4  12.8   9.61     43.6
 5 "g"       Singleton    9    12.1  11.3  11.9   8.56     43.9
 6 "g:"      Geminate     8.69 11.3  11.1  12.7  10.2      45.3
 7 "k"       Singleton    9.5  12.3  14.4   9.71  6.97     43.4
 8 "k:"      Geminate     9    14.7  16.1  10.1   7.37     48.2
 9 "l"       Singleton    8.69 11.9   6.33 11.5  10.2      40.0
10 "l:"      Geminate     8.81 11.3  10.0  10.0  11.5      42.8
11 "m"       Singleton    8.36 13.6   9.11 11.1   9.20     43.0
12 "m:"      Geminate     8.85 13.7  10.9   9.95  8.42     43.0
13 "m: "     Geminate    14    14.6  12.4   5.66  5.01     37.7
14 "n"       Singleton    8    15.1   4.44 11.6   8.99     40.2
15 "n:"      Geminate     8.21 21.4  10.1  10.2   9.32     51.0
16 "n: "     Geminate    11.3  32.0  10.4   8.09  7.94     58.5
17 "p"       Singleton    8.4  11.2  11.9   7.98  6.53     37.7
18 "p:"      Geminate     8.81 13.2  12.7   8.57 11.3      45.8
19 "t`"      Singleton    9    12.9  10.5   8.69  9.20     41.3
20 "t`:"     Geminate     9    13.1  13.1   8.39 10.6      45.2',
header = TRUE
)
```

Comment: The symbols including ":", "d_d" are necessary. For example, ":" represents "Geminate" value in column 'Consonant' Also refer to my reply to Ray above.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, @Pranav_b. I have edited the code and retained the colons. It seems 12/13 and 15/16 are duplicated when you were computing the mean values because there are trailing spaces in `m: ` and `n: ` in lines 13 and 16, respectively? `str_trim()` removed the padding spaces at extreme ends.

Comment: Thanks for bringing my attention to the mistyped entries. However, I could not run your code. It prints an error: `<error/dplyr:::mutate_error>
Problem with `mutate()` input `C2_xsampa`.
x could not find function "str_trim"
i Input `C2_xsampa` is `str_trim(C2_xsampa)`.
Backtrace:
  1. `%>%`(...)
 10. base::.handleSimpleError(...)
 11. dplyr:::h(simpleError(msg, call))
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context.`                                                                     

I have though rectrified the 'spacing' mistakes manually. Many thanks again.

Comment: That's great! I added the code for constructing the dataset. It seems `stringr` package is not loaded so R couldn't find `str_trim()`. The code works well at my end though. Anyway, good luck with your analysis!

Comment: Yes, I had to load 'stringr' package. I am new to tidy verse. My apologies. The code given by you works effectively.

Answer (score 2):

You could check that the values for the two columns are unique throughout the dataset

`df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['C2_xsampa','Consonant'])`

You can get the inverse `df[~df]` to get the rows that are incorrect

*edit* just saw the r language tag
I believe `distinct(select(df, C2_xsampa, Consonant))` will do

Answer (score 0):

My favorite approach for this is:

```r
subset(dat, duplicated(C2_xsampa) | duplicated(rev(C2_xsampa))
```

Comment: This already gives me the duplicated rows. The error was about the extra spaces that were put in the 'C2_xsampa' column for values, 'm:' and 'n:'. The solution is provided. Thanks for your suggestion. :)